# Is there a difference if we setup seccomp on docker daemon or directly when running?

Tags: docker, security, docker-compose, daemon, seccomp

I saw that there is two ways to setup a seccomp profile into docker, the first one by adding it to the configuration file of the docker daemon :

```json
{
    "seccomp-profile": "/etc/docker/profile.json",
    ...
}
```

But we can also add it directly when using `docker run` like such:

```bash
$ docker run --rm \
             -it \
             --security-opt seccomp=/path/to/seccomp/profile.json \
             hello-world
```

What I can't really get my head around is that, is there a difference? is it already setup for all containers if it's already in the daemon config file?
How can I verify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply that profile to all containers on the host, then both options should achieve the same result.

Changing the default seccomp profile for Docker is however [not recommended](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/#pass-a-profile-for-a-container). Instead, it is preferable to overwrite it on a per-container basis, as in your second example.